# SQL Job step to map a network drive to a specific letter

Tags: cmd, sql-server-2014, sql-job

I'm working on creating a SQL job and the first step of it I need to map to a network drive and make sure it always gets mapped to Z:.  Problem is if the drive is already mapped it fails with the error saying "The local device name is already in use" and if I manually disconnect the drive I get the same error.  I would ideal like to find a way to do this without having to delete and recreate the map every time.  Is this possible?

Right now I'm using

```
cmd.exe /c net use z: \\drivelocation DriveAccessCode
```

Again this results in "Device name is already in use" and if I disconnect the drive I get the same error.  I would like this to work without having to do

```
net use del z
```

everytime.  Even if there is a way to just check to see if it is mapped and if it is then go to step 2.  Any help would be amazing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if the drive is not mapped first:

`cmd.exe /c if not exist z:\* net use z: \\drivelocation DriveAccessCode`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks.  I tried if not exist but I think I included a "then" which wasn't necessary.